# Convert string to a RestSharp defined call method

Tags: c#, restsharp

So I'm trying to use RestSharp and create a function that handles everything and then call it alone, instead of using every single function in restsharp everytime.
What I'm having trouble with is having a String parameter be used as a definition inside Method of RestRequest.

```
    public void GetRestClient(string country, string method, string endpoint, string body = null) 
    {
        string url = getCountryUrl(country) + endpoint;
        RestClient client = new RestClient(url);
        RestRequest getRequest = new RestRequest(Method.**method**);
    }
```

Would this be a good way?

```
        RestRequest getRequest = new RestRequest((Method)Enum.Parse(typeof(Method), method));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
 RestRequest getRequest = new RestRequest((Method)Enum.Parse(typeof(Method), method));
```